# iOS 6 - YouTube App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

Currently on iOS 5 I have an iPhone application that contains web views which are youtube's video screen shot and when the user taps on the video the video opens up to fill the screen and plays...

I was wondering if the iOS 6 update would not work with my app since I use Youtube Videos...

Has anyone tested this out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been wondering about this too. According to this article you should be ok

http://gigaom.com/mobile/yes-youtube-is-gone-from-ios-6-so-what/

"I’ve verified on my own iPhone 4S that beta 4 of iOS does remove the YouTube app. But I’ve also verified that it really doesn’t change anything. Links to YouTube videos open up YouTube’s mobile web app and play just fine. "

Answer (score 0):

The removal of the YouTube app doesn't mean there'll be no support for playing YouTube videos. They can still be played by the browser or any other app.